# Azure Blob Copy stuck in Pending State

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to copy a VM from one subscription to another.  I've done this for 5 other VM's without issue.  All of the sudden, with THIS VM i'm having issues. The process continually gets hung when the OS disk is being copied.

The script I'm using is below:

```
foreach($disk in $allDisks)
{
    $blobName = $disk.MediaLink.Segments[2]
    $blobStorageAccount = $disk.MediaLink.Segments[1].Replace('/', '')
    $targetBlob = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -SrcContainer $blobStorageAccount -SrcBlob $blobName `
        -DestContainer vhds -DestBlob $blobName `
        -Context $sourceContext -DestContext $destContext -Force

    Write-Host "Copying blob $blobName"

    $copyState = $targetBlob | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState

    while ($copyState.Status -ne "Success")
    {
        $percent = ($copyState.BytesCopied / $copyState.TotalBytes) * 100
        Write-Host "Completed $('{0:N2}' -f $percent)%"
        sleep -Seconds 20
        $copyState = $targetBlob | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState
    }
```

When I check the status on the $copyState it's stuck at Pending. I've gone and used Stop-AzureStorageBlobCopy, deleted the destination blob and started over, but no matter what it's always just stuck in Pending state, with BytesCopied at 0.

The source VM has been stopped (deallocated) prior to copy.  There are no other pending copy operations that I can see, and I've checked every blob in the destination subscription manually.

I even tried a rename operation of the source blob in AzureStorageExplorer, which ended up creating a copy.  That copy completed without issue.  I tried copying the COPY of the original file over to the other subscription, and it also got stuck on "Pending".

Any ideas why I can't copy between the subscriptions?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with the same code. Earlier i have moved VMs without any trouble. But this time its stuck.

Comment: Having this problem in 2022, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I've run into throttling issues with pushing stuff into Azure blobs. I was pushing terabytes of data and was getting throttled. I got around this by changing the starting letter for the blobs. Apparently if you keep pushing to blobs that start with "a" for instance, eventually all actions to any blob starting with "a" is somehow considered the same group of jobs. Change your target blob to start with another letter, and you may see an improvement in performance with less throttling.